# Clear Timer on Compare or CTC in ATmega328P, Toggle OC0A on Compare Match

Tags: programming, atmega328, shift-register

I want to use the CTC on the ATmega328P to play same notes with a speaker, a project that I find in [this book](https://www.amazon.it/Make-Programming-Learning-Software-Hardware/dp/1449355781/ref=asc_df_1449355781/?tag=googshopit-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=90702551580&hvpos=1o1&hvnetw=g&hvrand=2812171719654097289&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=1008870&hvtargid=pla-93694981500&psc=1).

In the data sheet I read:

> For generating a waveform output in CTC mode, the OC0A output can be set to toggle its logical level on each compare match by setting the Compare Output mode bits to toggle mode (COM0A1:0 = 1). The OC0A value will not be visible on the port pin unless the data direction for the pin is set to output.

So I suppose that after I initialize the CTC and set as output the PIN PD5 (where I connected the speaker) the TCNT0 will change as a sawtooth wave (during time) and the PIN PD5 will be or 0V or 5V depending on the TCNT0 value. Is it correct?

So I change a little bit the code that is in the book:

```
#include <avr/io.h>                         
#include <util/delay.h>                     
#include "scale8.h" //Use to convert C2,C3 ... in numbers, for instance C2 = 100                            

static inline void initTimer(void) {         //Inializzazione del timer
    TCCR0A |= (1 << WGM01);                  /* CTC mode */
    TCCR0A |= (1 << COM0A0);                 /* Toggles pin each cycle through */
    TCCR0B |= (1 << CS00) | (1 << CS01);     /* CPU clock / 64 */
}

static inline void playNote(uint8_t period, uint16_t duration) {

    TCNT0 = 0;                                 /* reset the counter */
    OCR0A = period;                            /* set pitch */
    DDRD |= (1 << PD5);                        /* enable output on speaker */

    for(int i=0; i<duration; i++){             /* Variable delay */
        _delay_ms(1);
    }

    DDRD &= ~(1 << PD5);                        /* turn speaker off */
}

int main(void) {
    // -------- Inits --------- //
    initTimer();

    // ------ Event loop ------ //
    while (1) {
                                                    /* Play some notes */
        playNote(C2, 200);
        playNote(E2, 200);
        playNote(G2, 200);
        playNote(C3, 400);

        _delay_ms(1000);
        _delay_ms(1000);
        _delay_ms(1000);

    }                                                  
    return 0;                           
}
```

**The problem is that the voltage of the PIN PD5 doesn't change!** I try to print the voltage using serial but it's always 0V.

Comment: How are you measuring pin PD5? (PS I'd change `TCCR0B |= (1 << CS00) | (1 << CS01); ` to `TCCR0B = (1 << CS00) | (1 << CS01);`, so it doesn't depend on TCCR0B being zero.)

Comment: @Gerben Now I can't measure it directly, so I simple print PORTD and see the corresponding value of PD5. It's always 0.

Comment: The timer doesn't manipulate the port registers. It directly controls the physical port. PORTD doesn't get touched.

Comment: But reading PIND should reflect the actual values on the pins, no mater if it's alternate output (or even shorted output to the rail, you'll get that shorted level).